# Sing High notes and muscles

Tags: voice, vocal-range, voice-training

I'm training to reach high notes with my vocal teacher and she told me that have a connection between muscles and high notes and every time that have a high note I need to make a squat to strengthen the muscles until I reach to high without squat.
It's true?

Comment: Which set of muscles is your teacher considering?

Comment: I think the diaphragm muscles

Answer (score 2):

> *my vocal teacher and she told me that have a connection between muscles and high note*

Yes, she is right. The question is:
Which muscles?

*>and every time that have a high note I need to make a squat to strengthen the muscles until I reach to high without squat.*

I don't believe that believe that to strengthen your vocal cords. Your singing teacher is working with **imaginations**. Most people think to reach a high tone they have to stand on their tiptoes. That's contra productive and the imagination to take the stars from heaven is absolutely wrong. But If the teacher says you should make a squat she probably will give you the feeling or the imagination that you are still high above this tiny, little, high note and you can pick  it up like an apple from the ground.

*Every singer wants to expand his vocal range, and making high notes is the most impressive feat of them all. Nobody, however, is born to perfectly sing the highest notes! Vocal cords need training to get stronger just like other muscles. Start learning how to relax your muscles. Then warm up your voice and do specific exercises to help you expand your vocal range.*

Here are some good tips:

https://caricole.com/voice-lesson-5-quick-tips-sing-better-high-notes/

Comment: Thansk! I read the article and my teacher told me everything that mentioned there (Make a strong vocal, open your mounts and jaw etc)